# Clang set up compile C MacOS on Visual studio code

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code

I am being taught **C** at uni (NOT C++) and I am coding it on **MacOS catalina** and using **VSC** as my text editor and **clang** as my compiler. Two files created automatically, launch.json and task.json but it seems these are configured for C++ instead of C. When I run a simple code that calculates the area of a rectangle VSC prompts a message of running but **nothing happens**. Anyone has a solution? Ive invested more than 12 hours to try and fix this issue.

Task.json:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
  {
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "clang build active file",
    "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
    "args": [
      "-std=c17",
      "-stdlib=libcpp",
      "-g",
      "${file}",
      "-o",
      "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
    ],
    "options": {
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    }
  }
]
```

}

Launch.json

```
{

"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "name": "(lldb) Launch",
        "type":"cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? If so, what?

Comment: I dont, It simply doenst run. Do you want so see the code I am trying to run?